# Angular Material 2 table server-side pagination

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am trying to Achieve Angular Material 2, MatPaginator server side paging. How can I achieve that?

Below is the code example:

```
  <div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
                 [pageSize]="10"
                 [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Pagination Component:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';

/**
 * @title Table with pagination
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-pagination-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-pagination-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-pagination-example.html',
})
export class TablePaginationExample {
  displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  /**
   * Set the paginator after the view init since this component will
   * be able to query its view for the initialized paginator.
   */
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }
}

export interface Element {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
  {position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na'},
  {position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg'},
  {position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al'},
  {position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si'},
  {position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P'},
  {position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S'},
  {position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl'},
  {position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar'},
  {position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K'},
  {position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca'},
];
```

How can I achieve server side pagination, which would trigger on change event of next page click or page size changes to get next set of records.

https://stackblitz.com/angular/qxxpqbqolyb?file=app%2Ftable-pagination-example.ts

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Based on Wilfredo's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47994113/986160) I compiled a full working example since some pieces were missing from question as well. Here is a more general case for server-side pagination and sorting using Angular 5 and Material Design (still need to plug in filtering) - hopefully it will be helpful to someone:

**Paging Component:**

```ts
import { ViewChild, Component, Inject, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EntityJson } from './entity.json';
import { EntityService } from './entity.service';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge';
import { of as observableOf } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators/startWith';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators/switchMap';

@Component({
    selector: 'entity-latest-page',
    providers: [EntityService],
    styles: [`
        :host mat-table {
           display: flex;
           flex-direction: column;
           min-width: 100px;
           max-width: 800px;
           margin: 0 auto;
        }
    `],
    template:
    `<mat-card>
        <mat-card-title>Entity List 
        <button mat-button [routerLink]="['/create/entity']">
            CREATE
        </button>
        </mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-content>
            <mat-table #table matSort [dataSource]="entitiesDataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z2">
                <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Id </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
                <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
            </mat-table>
        </mat-card-content>
        <mat-card-content>
            <mat-paginator #paginator [length]="resultsLength"
                [pageSize]="5"
                [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]">
            </mat-paginator>
        </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
    `
})
export class EntityLatestPageComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    private entities: EntityJson[];
    private entitiesDataSource: MatTableDataSource<EntityJson> = new MatTableDataSource();
    private displayedColumns = ['id', 'name'];

    resultsLength = 0;
    isLoadingResults = false;
    isRateLimitReached = false;

    @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
    @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

    public constructor( @Inject(EntityService) private entityService: EntityService) {
    }

    public ngAfterViewInit() {

        // If the user changes the sort order, reset back to the first page.
        this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);
        merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
        .pipe(
            startWith({}),
            switchMap(() => {
            this.isLoadingResults = true;
            return this.entityService.fetchLatest(this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, 
                  this.paginator.pageIndex + 1, this.paginator.pageSize, 
                  (total) =>  this.resultsLength = total);
            }),
            map(data => {
            this.isLoadingResults = false;
            this.isRateLimitReached = false;
            //alternatively to response headers;
            //this.resultsLength = data.total;
            return data;
            }),
            catchError(() => {
            this.isLoadingResults = false;
            this.isRateLimitReached = true;
            return observableOf([]);
            })
        ).subscribe(data => this.entitiesDataSource.data = data);
    } 
}
```

---

**Service:**

```ts
import { EntityJson } from './entity.json';
import { ApiHelper } from '../common/api.helper';
import { Http, Headers, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../auth/authentication.service';
import { stringify } from 'query-string';

@Injectable()
export class EntityService {

    private options: RequestOptions;
    private apiPrefix: string;
    private apiEndpoint: string;

    constructor(
        @Inject(Http) private http: Http,
        @Inject(AuthenticationService) private authService: AuthenticationService) {

        this.options = authService.prepareRequestHeaders();
        this.apiPrefix = 'http://localhost:4200/api/v1/';
        this.apiEndpoint = this.apiPrefix + 'entities';
    }

    public fetchLatest(sort: string = '', order: string = '', page: number = 1, perPage: number = 5, initTotal: Function = () => {}): Observable<EntityJson[]> {
        return this.http.get(this.apiEndpoint +'?' + EntityService.createUrlQuery({sort: {field: sort, order: order}, pagination: { page, perPage }}), this.options)
            .map((res) => {
                const total = res.headers.get('x-total-count').split('/').pop();
                initTotal(total);
                return JSON.parse(res.text()).content
            });
    }

    //should be put in a util
    static createUrlQuery(params: any) {
        if (!params) {
            return "";
        }

        let page;
        let perPage;
        let field;
        let order;
        let query: any = {};
        if (params.pagination) {
             page = params.pagination.page;
             perPage =  params.pagination.perPage;
             query.range = JSON.stringify([
                page,
                perPage,
            ]);
        }
        if (params.sort) {
            field = params.sort.field;
            order = params.sort.order;
            if (field && order) {
                query.sort = JSON.stringify([field, order]);
            }
            else {
                query.sort = JSON.stringify(['id', 'ASC']);
            }
        }
        if (!params.filter) {
            params.filter = {};
        }
        if (Array.isArray(params.ids)) {
            params.filter.id = params.ids;
        }

        if (params.filter) {
            query.filter = JSON.stringify(params.filter)
        }
        console.log(query, stringify(query));
        return stringify(query);
    }
}
```

---

**Spring Boot Rest Controller Endpoint**

```java
@GetMapping("entities")
public Iterable<Entity> filterBy(
        @RequestParam(required = false, name = "filter") String filterStr,
        @RequestParam(required = false, name = "range") String rangeStr, @RequestParam(required = false, name="sort") String sortStr) {
    //my own helpers - for source: https://github.com/zifnab87/react-admin-java-rest
    //FilterWrapper wrapper = filterService.extractFilterWrapper(filterStr, rangeStr, sortStr);
    //return filterService.filterBy(wrapper, repo);
}
```

---

**Some notes:**

1. Make sure you import Modules: `MatTableModule`,
   `MatPaginatorModule` and `MatSortModule` along other modules from Material Design.
2. I decided to populate `resultsLength` (total) from Response-Header `x-total-count` which I populate through Spring Boot `@ControllerAdvice`. Alternatively you can get this information from the object returned from `EntityService` (e.g `Page` for Spring Boot) although that implies you will need to use `any` as return type or declare wrapper class objects for all of the entities in your project if you want to be "type-safe".

Comment: Hi. How do you link paginator and datasource in your example?

Comment: Hi! resultsLength contains the total number of elements. For my case I send this information using a ControllerAdvice and I add a header that contains the total number of elements matching a JPA repositoty query. Then based on the pageSize paginator is calculating the number of pages needed. Check the arrow function I am passing in fetchLatest(). Hope this helps.

Comment: Sergey, I think the point is that they're *not* linked at all. Just indirectly by providing events that update the data source and reading the total resultsLength.

Comment: @Michali , can you please explain the EntityLatestPageComponent  class logic with respect to fetching data from back end ? The logic inside ngAfterViewInit method of this class is very difficult to understand

Comment: @Atul you can have a look at my github repository here: https://github.com/zifnab87/react-admin-java-rest/tree/master/src/main/java/reactAdmin/rest

it is an implementation to support the REST endpoint conventions of admin-on-rest/react-admin default data-provider:  https://marmelab.com/react-admin/DataProviders.html#example-response-processing - as for ngAfterViewInit I just extended it from answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47994113/986160

Comment: @Atul More specifically https://github.com/zifnab87/react-admin-java-rest/blob/master/src/main/java/reactAdmin/rest/services/FilterService.java

Comment: @Michali : Thanks a lot for your repply . I will go through these and let you know if any queries . Is there any way we can have chat over any messenger ?

Comment: @Michali: If I comment out  startWith({}) , the switchMap doesn't get called and eventually subscribe method doesn't get called. No data is returned

Comment: @Atul not sure how startWith() works but from what I understand is since you are piping multiple transformations of the data you need to start with an empty object

Comment: to link the paginator to make new calls use  (page)="  getServerData($event)"

Comment: Why would I want to use MatTableDataSource here instead of a plain array? What's the benefit?

Answer (score 14):

I figured out this problem following [Table retrieving data through HTTP](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) from angular material docs.

What the example says is, use `ngAfterViewInit()` plus observables to handle everything on the table, pagination, sorting and other stuff that you need, code:

```js
import {Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {merge} from 'rxjs/observable/merge';
import {of as observableOf} from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import {startWith} from 'rxjs/operators/startWith';
import {switchMap} from 'rxjs/operators/switchMap';

/**
 * @title Table retrieving data through HTTP
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-http-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-http-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-http-example.html',
})
export class TableHttpExample implements AfterViewInit {
  displayedColumns = ['created', 'state', 'number', 'title'];
  exampleDatabase: ExampleHttpDao | null;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

  resultsLength = 0;
  isLoadingResults = false;
  isRateLimitReached = false;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.exampleDatabase = new ExampleHttpDao(this.http);

    // If the user changes the sort order, reset back to the first page.
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);

    merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
      .pipe(
        startWith({}),
        switchMap(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = true;
          return this.exampleDatabase!.getRepoIssues(
            this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, this.paginator.pageIndex);
        }),
        map(data => {
          // Flip flag to show that loading has finished.
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.isRateLimitReached = false;
          this.resultsLength = data.total_count;

          return data.items;
        }),
        catchError(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          // Catch if the GitHub API has reached its rate limit. Return empty data.
          this.isRateLimitReached = true;
          return observableOf([]);
        })
      ).subscribe(data => this.dataSource.data = data);
  }
}

export interface GithubApi {
  items: GithubIssue[];
  total_count: number;
}

export interface GithubIssue {
  created_at: string;
  number: string;
  state: string;
  title: string;
}

/** An example database that the data source uses to retrieve data for the table. */
export class ExampleHttpDao {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getRepoIssues(sort: string, order: string, page: number): Observable<GithubApi> {
    const href = 'https://api.github.com/search/issues';
    const requestUrl =
        `${href}?q=repo:angular/material2&sort=${sort}&order=${order}&page=${page + 1}`;

    return this.http.get<GithubApi>(requestUrl);
  }
}
```

Look that everything is handled inside the ngAfterViewInit thanks to observables. the line `this.resultsLength = data.total_count;` is expecting that your service is returning the data with total register counts, in my case I'm using springboot and its returned everything that I need.

If you need more clarification, write any comment and I gonna update the answer, but checking the example from the docs you'll figure it.

Comment: I'm trying to use paginator with server side pagination too, how do you manage the next page and previous page events? thnx

Comment: @bre How you are subscribing the event to the control it will detects when any event will fire and refresh the data.

Comment: hi thank for quick replay but i ended using ngxdatatable :-)

Comment: @Wilfredo: Can you please share the Rest Controller implementation? I'm facing issues to integrate it with Rest Controller.

Comment: @Wilfredo: I figured out and integrated with Rest Controller. Thanks

Comment: What about building a reusable table based on this table?

Comment: Why would I want to use `MatTableDataSource` here instead of a plain array? What's the benefit?

Comment: @atiyar Although I have about a year and half without working with angular, I recall that it was because I was using Material, so, for a Mat table as far as I concerned it's needed https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview but yes you can use a simple array.

Answer (score 4):

This is a combination of [Michail Michailidis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48480886/213246) along with the [official table pagination example](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/material-examples/table-pagination/table-pagination-example.ts), condensed down into a single file, and using a mock "network" service class that returns an Observable and simulates latency.

If you have a Material 2 + Angular 5 project up and running, you should be able to drop this into a new component file, add it to your modules list, and start hacking. At least it should be a lower barrier to entry for getting started.

```js
import { ViewChild, Component, Inject, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatPaginator, MatSort, MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge';
import { of as observableOf } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators/catchError';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators/startWith';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators/switchMap';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-element-table',
  styles: [`
    :host mat-table {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      min-width: 100px;
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
  `],
  template: `
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-title>Element List</mat-card-title>
    <mat-card-content>
      <mat-table #table matSort [dataSource]="elementDataSource" class="mat-elevation-z2">

        <!-- Position Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
         <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> No. </mat-header-cell>
         <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
         <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Name </mat-header-cell>
         <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Weight Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
         <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Weight </mat-header-cell>
         <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- Symbol Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
         <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Symbol </mat-header-cell>
         <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

        <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
        <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
      </mat-table>
    </mat-card-content>
    <mat-card-content>
      <mat-paginator #paginator [length]="resultsLength"
        [pageSize]="5"
        [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"
        showFirstLastButtons>
      </mat-paginator>
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
  `
})
export class ElementTableComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  public elementDataSource = new MatTableDataSource<PeriodicElement>();
  public displayedColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];

  private entities: PeriodicElement[];
  private elementService = new ElementService();

  resultsLength = 0;
  isLoadingResults = false;
  isRateLimitReached = false;

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  public constructor() {
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => this.paginator.pageIndex = 0);
    merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page)
      .pipe(
        startWith({ data: [], resultsLength: 0 } as ElementResult),
        switchMap(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = true;
          return this.elementService.fetchLatest(
            this.sort.active, this.sort.direction,
            this.paginator.pageIndex + 1, this.paginator.pageSize);
        }),
        map(result => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.isRateLimitReached = false;
          this.resultsLength = result.resultsLength;
          return result.data;
        }),
        catchError(() => {
          this.isLoadingResults = false;
          this.isRateLimitReached = true;
          return observableOf([]);
        })
      ).subscribe(data => this.elementDataSource.data = data);
  }
}

// Simulates server-side rendering
class ElementService {
  constructor() { }

  fetchLatest(active: string, direction: string, pageIndex: number, pageSize: number): Observable<ElementResult> {

    active = active || 'position';
    const cmp = (a, b) => (a[active] < b[active] ? -1 : 1);
    const rev = (a, b) => cmp(b, a);
    const [l, r] = [(pageIndex - 1) * pageSize, pageIndex * pageSize];

    const data = [...ELEMENT_DATA]
      .sort(direction === 'desc' ? rev : cmp)
      .filter((_, i) => l <= i && i < r);

    // 1 second delay to simulate network request delay
    return new BehaviorSubject({ resultsLength: ELEMENT_DATA.length, data }).debounceTime(1000);
  }
}

interface ElementResult {
  resultsLength: number;
  data: PeriodicElement[];
}

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  { position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H' },
  { position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He' },
  { position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li' },
  { position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be' },
  { position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B' },
  { position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C' },
  { position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N' },
  { position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O' },
  { position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F' },
  { position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne' },
  { position: 11, name: 'Sodium', weight: 22.9897, symbol: 'Na' },
  { position: 12, name: 'Magnesium', weight: 24.305, symbol: 'Mg' },
  { position: 13, name: 'Aluminum', weight: 26.9815, symbol: 'Al' },
  { position: 14, name: 'Silicon', weight: 28.0855, symbol: 'Si' },
  { position: 15, name: 'Phosphorus', weight: 30.9738, symbol: 'P' },
  { position: 16, name: 'Sulfur', weight: 32.065, symbol: 'S' },
  { position: 17, name: 'Chlorine', weight: 35.453, symbol: 'Cl' },
  { position: 18, name: 'Argon', weight: 39.948, symbol: 'Ar' },
  { position: 19, name: 'Potassium', weight: 39.0983, symbol: 'K' },
  { position: 20, name: 'Calcium', weight: 40.078, symbol: 'Ca' },
];
```

Btw, [this issue on material2 about filtering](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/6178) might be useful if you're looking to implement filtering yourself.

Comment: I get the error: Type '{} | PeriodicElement[]' is not assignable to type 'PeriodicElement[]'.   Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'PeriodicElement[]'.
I linie 102: ).subscribe(data => this.elementDataSource.data = data);

any idea?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is the type unification rules changed, and maybe 'return observableOf([]);' inside catchError doesn't cleanly unify with PeriodicElement[] anymore. Try: 'return observableOf([] as PeriodicElement[]);'